# Differences between MessageBox, Dialog and PopUp

Tags: wxpython

I'm making a cyclic full-screen wizard for a kiosk and I want to have custom messageboxes/dialogs/popups to appear according to errors in the service or Yes/No alerts.

I already have a working prototype using wx.PopUp and wx.PopUpTransient classes, but now I want to customize these windows (bitmap border with adaptive window sizing accordingly to text length and selected margin). 
Test run didn't work, and now I read that there's also wx.Dialog and wx.MessageBox classes that are "useful" in those cases.

What are the difference between them?

and

Their subclasses related to the paint procedure are similar to those treated in http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls ?

For what I get, I should use wx.Dialog subclasses to request user input and MessageBox to pass information (or create a light version of a Dialog) to the user; then PopUp could be a predefined and quick and dirt version of a MessageBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MessageDialog](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MessageDialog-class.html) is just a simple way to ask the user simple questions. I believe the MessageBox class actually can let you get some input. There's also a [GenericMessageDialog](https://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.genericmessagedialog-module.html) that can be useful as it has a few extra features and it's written in pure Python.

The `wx.Dialog` is the ultimate as it's a base class and you can build whatever kind of dialog you want with it. For the most control, you should definitely go with that.

The popup controls are useful for popup messages. I usually see them used for creating a context menus. Depending on your needs, the ToasterBox widget might evern be helpful for you as it can pop up a message and then disappear in a fun little way.

I would recommend checking out the wxPython demo package. It has examples of all the dialogs. These following links are also useful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/10/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-2-of-2/
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/

Comment: And about their Paint Procedures. I forgot in my code a line binding the `wx.EVT_PAINT` event for my paint method. That's why it wasn't working. (Now draws a monochrome garbage, but it draws something).